# ASP.NET C#,Javascript

Tags: asp.net

Want to populate the second dropdown values based on selection first of first drop down.

id  Bankname    Branchname
1   HDFC    AMT
2   HDFC    gag
3   icic    AMsfsaT
4   bpjn    daD

in the first drop down if I select the HDFC then in second dropdown AMT,gag should come.

I am using following code to fill first dropdown.

```
    string com = "Select * from mst_bank";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dt);
    ddlbank.DataSource = dt;
    ddlbank.DataBind();
    ddlbank.DataTextField = "Bankname";
    ddlbank.DataValueField = "ID";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 2 DropDownLists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" /><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" />
```

And your code behind will be:

```
private string conStr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillDDL1();
        FillDDL2(ddl1.SelectedValue);
    }
}

protected void FillDDL1()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from mst_bank", con);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ddl1.DataSource = ds;
        ddl1.DataTextField = "Bankname";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //work with exception
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillDDL2(ddl1.SelectedValue);
}

protected void FillDDL2(string id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from second_table where BANK_ID = @id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ddl1.DataSource = ds;
        ddl1.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "ID";
        ddl1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //work with exception
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

On PostBack we fill dropdown1 and dropdown2, using corresponding value from the dropdown1. Method *ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged* will be occur when user changes selection, and dropdown2 will be filled with a corresponding values. Of course, you have to change a SQL-query there.

Comment: THNKS  bro that help me i was looking exactly for that